# Présent de l'indicatif et imparfait du subjonctif dans la même phrase ?

Tags: subjonctif, concordance-des-temps

Dans un article du [monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/pixels/article/2017/07/27/la-russie-accusee-d-avoir-cree-de-faux-comptes-facebook-pour-surveiller-des-proches-de-macron_5165586_4408996.html) je trouve la phrase suivante :

> Les agences de renseignement américaines disent soupçonner que des pirates proches du pouvoir russe **fussent** à l’origine de cette publication, mais aucune preuve d’une éventuelle implication n’a pu être apportée.

(Article essentiellement au passé, mis en gras par mes soins)

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi on utilise pas simplement **soient**.

Ai-je raison d'être surpris ?

Comment: Si on l'avait dit avec certitude, aurait-il été « est » ou « a été » ? Je dirais le deuxième. Donc *soient* serait également pour un travail en cours, *fussent* pour le passé. Or il s'agit d'un évènement unique qui a déjà eu lieu pour la publication des courriels.

Comment: (Pour ma première phrase je voulais proposer « sont » vs. « ont été », bien sûr ...)

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit dans cette phrase d'exprimer une information incertaine non vérifiée. C'est le conditionnel qu'on s'attendrait à avoir dans cette phrase.

> Le conditionnel [...] s'emploie encore pour marquer un fait douteux, éventuel, en particulier lorsqu'on présente ce fait comme un ouï-dire, comme une assertion dont on ne se veut pas garant. (*Le Bon Usage*, 10<sup>e</sup> édition, § 739)

C'est bien de ça qu'il s'agit dans l'article du *Monde* qui rapporte des soupçons pour lesquels il n'y a pas de preuves.

Donc naturellement on dirait :

> Les agences de renseignement américaines disent soupçonner que des pirates proches du pouvoir russe **seraient** à l’origine de cette publication...

Mais l'imparfait du subjonctif peut être employé à la place du conditionnel pour exprimer un fait incertain.

> Après un verbe principal au présent, on trouve un subjonctif imparfait pour exprimer un fait possible ou soumis à une condition (il est l’équivalent du conditionnel dans la langue standard). *[Bonjour de France](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/le-subjonctif-imparfait.html)*.

Cet utilisation du subjonctif est cependant **très littéraire** et reste du **domaine de l'écrit**, d'autant plus que l'imparfait du subjonctif tend à se raréfier de plus en plus.