# Comment « serait-ce » a-t-il pris le sens de « même » ?

Tags: étymologie

Quelles notions sémantiques expliquent comment « serait-ce » indique une supposition extrême ?

[1](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ne-f%C3%BBt-ce-que-ne-serait-ce-que.1342290/#post-6934229) et [2](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/f%C3%BBt-ce-dans-100-ans.525968/#post-2970821) donnent « même » comme synonyme.

[Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%c3%aatre/31549/locution?q=serait-ce#162309) :

> **Littéraire.** Fût-ce, serait-ce, indiquent une supposition extrême :
> [Exemple :] Je le suivrais partout, fût-ce au bout du monde.

[CNRTL, 3e Section, 1](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%c3%aatre/31549/locution?q=serait-ce#162309)  :

> c) Ne serait-ce que, ne fût-ce que (= quand ce ne serait que). Loc. à valeur restrictive et conditionnelle, toujours au sing., en position marginale ou en incise. [...]
>
> − *Fût-ce.* Même sens

Comment: *Quelles notions sémantiques expliquent comment « serait-ce » indique une supposition extrême ?* Pas sémantique, grammaticales. Parce que le conditionnel (*serait-ce*) est le mode de la supposition et que le subjonctif peut parfois remplacer le conditionnel pour exprimer un fait possible ou soumis à une condition. Voir [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26612/358) à ce sujet.

Answer (score 4):

Partons d'un exemple:

> Ne voudrais-tu pas m'aider, même une seule fois ?

Dans cet exemple, le verbe être est omis.
On pourrait aussi bien dire:

> Ne voudrais-tu pas m'aider, même si ce n'était qu'une seule fois ?

Maintenant, la construction "même si + imparfait" peut se transformer en conditionnel avec inversion sujet-verbe.
Par exemple "Même si je le voulais, je ne pourrais pas" peut aussi bien se dire "Le voudrais-je que je ne pourrais pas" ; on trouve aussi "Le saurais-je que je ne te le dirais pas."
Donc logiquement :

> Ne voudrais-tu pas m'aider, ne serait-ce qu'une seule fois ?

Remarquons que c'est une erreur commune à l'oral d'utiliser le conditionnel pour remplacer si + imparfait ("je l'aurais fait, je t'l'aurais pas dit").

Comment: Merci. Pourriez-vous préciser comment `la construction "même si + imparfait" peut se transformer en conditionnel avec inversion sujet-verbe`?

Comment: SVP, pourriez-vous répondre dans votre réponse propre, et non pas à titre de commentaires qui sont plus laborieux à lire ?